# Messing with ListView in Android

Tags: android

Good day to everyone, I am new to Android, I keep on messing with ListView. The code below wont work! I dont know why. Please let me know where's the mistake.

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("Follow Me!");
    data.add("This is now.");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

After running the above code, my adroid device will show a dialogue saying:
"Sorry!
The application CodeGenerator has stopped unexpectedly. System failed to repair the error. Please use other software."

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I changed the code, and its running now. Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("Follow Me!");
    data.add("This is now.");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

Still a mystery for me, why my first code did not work! If anyone can explain that, please let me know! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure why your first code is not working, but I know why this code is working! You are using `ListActivity` in this code. `ListActivity` has a default view of its own, so you need not use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Instead ListActivity uses an android xml layout file of its own internally.

Answer (score 1):

The `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line should be immediately after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.

What this
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
line does is it basically displays the screen (your android xml to the user). Now when you do

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

You are trying to get your `ListView` from your xml in your java code. But if you dont set the content itself, then there is no ListView and hence your application is crashing.

Comment: Actually, that is my problem because no error has been recorded in logcat... Just a dialog saying "Sorry! The application CodeGenerator has stopped unexpectedly. System failed to repair the error. Please use other software."

Comment: That is not possible. Reconnect your device and see if you are getting the logs. Are you saying that the other logs are coming but not the crash logs?

Comment: I did what you said, I reconnected my device but still no errors has been recorded in logcat, still crashing....

Comment: Thank you Antrromet for your help! I appreciate it!